# Help .htaccess Server error

Tags: .htaccess

i added this code to .htaccess and place it the root of my website:

but it's seems it doesn't work, I'm getting server error page

can you please tell me what i did wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of it. That's PHP code, .htaccess is for Apache code/syntax. I think you want something like:

```
<Limit GET POST>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 69.20.39.30
</Limit>
```

Specify the IPs that you want, assuming this is some sort of restricted area.

Comment: Why would you only want to limit GET and POST?

Comment: That's just the first thing that popped in my head as it's the syntax I have used thus far. Would you not rely on the Limit directive and just have the Order/Deny/Allow straight up in the .htaccess or does it need to be contained in some directive?